# Laravel. Cannot use object of type StdClass as array after toArray() convert

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

For me it looks weird.

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I converted my query to array.

```
$query = DB::table('users')->where('name','=','Alex')->get()->toArray();
```

Checked my variable `gettype($query);` and it says `Array`.
 Also checked it with `var_dump($query);` and it also shows `Array`. 
So why while looping my `$query` in foreach I have to use `$item->name` and can't access to items as array `$item['name']` ?

Comment: Could be an array of objects, not an array of arrays

Comment: @kerbholz yea, you are right. Thanks for an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using `toArray()`, you get an array of objects, so you still need to use:

```
$item->name
```

If you want to convert it to an array of arrays, do this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'Alex')->get();
$users->transform(function($i) {
    return (array)$i;
});
$array = $users->toArray();
```

Comment: Same issue, I always mix brackets and arrow. :) Thank you

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get result as `array` then use `get()`

```
$query = DB::table('users')->where('name','=','Alex')->get();
```

if you want to get result as `object` use `first()`

```
$query = DB::table('users')->where('name','=','Alex')->first();
```

Comment: get() returns a Collection of objects, so I still have to use ->, and first() returns only the first row

Comment: @qqmydarling , so what output you want ?

Comment: @qqmydarling , using  get()->toArray(); is wrong , you are converting array to array , that is incorrect

Comment: as I said I was interested why I should access items as an object, but now I know. Thanks for a feedback.
No, get() returns a collection of objects, not an array